# Openfire: org.jivesoftware.openfire.pubsub.PubSubPersistenceManager - Incorrect syntax near the keyword ‘LEFT’

Tags: sql-server, openfire

Any idea what could be causing this error to be constantly produced in all.log and error. log. Openfire 4.3.2 on Windows connected to SQL Server 2012 (SP4) - although it shouldn’t matter. Could it be a result of incorrect SQL in ofProperty table? Where to look?
We have a working web/Candy.js chat application…

```
2019.05.08 20:46:12 ERROR [TaskEngine-pool-16]: org.jivesoftware.openfire.pubsub.PubSubPersistenceManager - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:1069) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:223) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:223) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.pubsub.PubSubPersistenceManager.purgeItems(PubSubPersistenceManager.java:1893) [xmppserver-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.pubsub.PubSubPersistenceManager.access$000(PubSubPersistenceManager.java:57) [xmppserver-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.pubsub.PubSubPersistenceManager$2.run(PubSubPersistenceManager.java:283) [xmppserver-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
```

Comment: That sounds like an SQL error, but it could be a lot of things with just that much to go on. You could have faulty customer SQL, yes. One possible thing to check - is there a column called LEFT (usually paired with TOP)? If so, make sure any custom SQL trying to access it uses [LEFT], as it is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

We used SQL Profiler to check for `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'` message.
here's what we got: error was produced by the following bad SQL

```
DELETE FROM ofPubsubItem
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM ofPubsubItem WHERE serviceID= @P0  AND nodeID= @P1  ORDER BY creationDate DESC LIMIT  @P2 ) AS noDelete
            ON ofPubsubItem.id = noDelete.id
WHERE ...
```

This SQL is incorrect, correct one would include 'FROM ofPubsubItem' twice like

```
DELETE FROM ofPubsubItem
FROM ofPubsubItem LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM ofPubsubItem WHERE serviceID= @P0  AND nodeID= @P1  ORDER BY creationDate DESC LIMIT  @P2 ) AS noDelete
            ON ofPubsubItem.id = noDelete.id
WHERE
```

I'm going to submit bug report to Openfire. Not sure if that SQL syntax ANSI or SQL Server specific, but Openfire is supposed to support SQL Server.